# Assign the value of a function to a variable

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to assign the result of a MySQL query to a variable so I can send it to a post request.

Here is my code:

```
// mysqlCRUD.js

buscarUsuario: function(usuario, cb) {
   console.log(usuario);
   con.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nick = ?', usuario,  function(err, results) {
     return cb(null, results.length);
   });
},

//index.js

router.post('/comprobarUsuario', function(req, res, next) {
   resultado = mysqlCRUD.buscarUsuario(req.body.nick, function(err, data){
     return data;
   });
   res.send(resultado);
});
```

The post request comes from a jquery:

```
$.post('/comprobarUsuario', { nick: nick}, function(data) {
    console.log("Respuesta Usuario: " + data);
});
```

But I don't know why the result never reaches the post request.
Could anybody please help me.

Comment: It doesn't hit `/comprobarUsuario` ?

Comment: Yes, It does hit /comprobarUsuario but the data never reaches the jquery post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

**The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.**

```
router.post('/comprobarUsuario', function(req, res, next) {
    mysqlCRUD.buscarUsuario(req.body.nick, function(err, data){
       return res.send(data.toString());
    });
});
```

Comment: Change what you suggest but still no data getting to my jquery post request.

Comment: Try this one and let me know the `console` output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your, here is the response: Request: andres
Data: 1
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead routes\index.js:55:19
POST /comprobarUsuario 1 55.048 ms - -

Comment: this one should help you.

Comment: YEEEESSSS. Whos awesome, YOUR AWESOME. I have been delaying with this for 2 days. WORK PERFECT. THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)